# Inserir nome ao invés do id do value option

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Gravar no Banco de dados

```html
    //Ids
 $codEstado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'estado', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
 $codCidade = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cidade', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
 $codBairro = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'bairro', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
 //Inserir no bando de dados
 $sqlBairro = "INSERT INTO cadastros (estadonome,cidadenome,bairronome) VALUES (:estadonome, :cidadenome, :bairronome)";
 $resBairro = $conexao->prepare($sqlBairro);

 $resBairro->execute(array(
  ':estadonome' => $codEstado,
  ':cidadenome' => $codCidade,
  ':bairronome' => $codBairros
 ));
 $resBairro->fetchAll();
```

Seleções...

```html
<!--Seleções cep-->
  <select name="estado" id="estado" required>
   <option value="">Selecione</option>
   <?php foreach ($estados as $estado) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $estado['id'] ?>"><?php echo $estado['nome'] ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
  </select>

 <label for="cidade">Cidade:</label>
 <select name="cidade" id="cidade" disabled required>
  <option value="<?php $cidade; ?>">Selecione um estado</option>
 </select>

 <label for="bairro">Bairro:</label>
 <select name="bairro" id="bairro" disabled required>
  <option value="<?php $bairro; ?>">Selecione uma cidade</option>
 </select>
```

Parte do código que está gravando o id, lembrando... se colocar $bairro['nome'] no lugar do value não vai gravar nada...

```html
<?php foreach ($bairros as $bairro) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $bairro['id'] ?>"><?php echo $bairro['nome'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Tudo no código está normal, mas ao invés de gravar o nome, ele grava o id na tabela.

Me ajudem.
Grato!

Comment: Qual o tipo do campo bairro no seu banco de dados?

Comment: varchar(255) amigo...

Answer (score 1):

No seu `PHP` você esta gravando o retorno do `input` em `$codBairro` e quando você passa os parâmetros você envia `$codBairros`, os dois devem ser iguais:

```
//Inserir no bando de dados
$sqlBairro = "INSERT INTO cadastros (estadonome,cidadenome,bairronome) VALUES (:estadonome, :cidadenome, :bairronome)";
$resBairro = $conexao->prepare($sqlBairro);

$resBairro->execute(array(
    ':estadonome' => $codEstado,
    ':cidadenome' => $codCidade,
    ':bairronome' => $codBairro
));
$resBairro->fetchAll();
```

Outro detalhe, você esta tentando passar uma `string` e pedindo para o `PHP` verificar um inteiro neste ponto:

```
$codBairro = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'bairro', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

Tente passar o `POST` direto, e verifique se salva:

```
$codBairro = $_POST('bairro');
```

Agora você pode montar suas `options` assim:

```
<?php foreach ($bairros as $bairro) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $bairro['nome'] ?>"><?php echo $bairro['nome'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Testei... está gravando em branco amigo....

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: deu certo pra gravar só o bairro pq os ids anterios são referencias um do outro na escolha do select... Obrigado por está ajudando...

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado a quem me ajudou, consegui de outra forma...

```html
  $codEstado=$_POST["estado"];
  $queryEstado = "SELECT * FROM estado WHERE id='$codEstado'";
  $stmtEstado = $conexao->prepare($queryEstado);
  $stmtEstado->execute();
  $rowEstado = $stmtEstado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $codEstado = $rowEstado["nome"];
  
  $codCidade = $_POST['cidade'];
  $queryCidade = "SELECT * FROM cidade WHERE id='$codCidade'";
  $stmtCidade = $conexao->prepare($queryCidade);
  $stmtCidade->execute();
  $rowCidade = $stmtCidade->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $codCidade = $rowCidade["nome"];  
  
  $codBairro = $_POST['bairro'];
  $queryBairro = "SELECT * FROM bairro WHERE id='$codBairro'";
  $stmtBairro = $conexao->prepare($queryBairro);
  $stmtBairro->execute();
  $rowBairro = $stmtBairro->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $codBairro = $rowBairro["nome"];
```